# downloading email attachment in Silverlight

Tags: c#, file-io, silverlight-4.0

I'm using VS2010, C# to develop a web-based (in-browser) Silverlight 4 app, I'm reading emails (currently gmail) using IMAP, I use a WCF in my Silverlight to access gmail data. Everything is going fine but I have problem in downloading attachments, I can get email attachments in byte array, there is no problem in saving these bytes using Response.Stream or File.WriteAllBytes (in ASP.NET pages). But when I want to save them in my SL app I have two problems: it seems that I cannot use Response in my WCF, and also File.WriteAllBytes give me this error: File operation not permitted, access denied to myfilename. what are my options to download attachments in my SL app? should I return my file data as byte[] to SL app or I should save them directly in WCF?

what methods should I use? response? file? or something else, thanks

Comment: Can you clarify if you're able to get your attachment as `byte[]` in Silverlight?

Comment: yes, as I said I can have my attachment file as a byte array in Silverlight, but I cannot save it to client disk!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you save `byte[]` to file in SL4:

```
    private void SaveFile(byte[] bytes)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveDialog.DefaultExt = ".stuff";
        saveDialog.Filter = "Funky Stuff File|*.stuff|All Files|*.*";
        saveDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
        bool? dialogResult = saveDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogResult == true)
        {
            using (Stream ms = (Stream)saveDialog.OpenFile())
            {
                ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                ms.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used SaveFileDialog yesterday, but I didn't create file until I closed my project, but it works now! thanks, is there any way that I make this window like ASP.NET file download window? for instance can I fix the filename as filename is already known (it is a mail attachmant), I should use default file name?

Comment: You can't use default file name in Silverlight's `SaveFileDialog` because of security concerns. As for making your window more like ASP.NET file download window, can't tell you from the top of my head but it doesn't sound impossible. I'm not ASP person but maybe there's a way of invoking file download via hosting site...but then you'd probably have to send file forth and back between client and server...think I'm going too far with this :)

Comment: Or try exploring what Elevated Trust or Isolated Storage may bring to the table

Comment: Thanks StaWho, thanks Stackoverflow! it is working great! of course I should find a way to have default file name, but extension is just fine, you helped me a lot